# GenericJDBCException: Invalid column type: getCLOB not implemented

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I am trying to migrate from JBoss 5.1 to JBoss 7.1.1 and currently have this problem.
Whenever I try to get an object from the database that contains a CLOB field, this error is thrown:

```
11:48:58,974 INFO  [org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Invalid column type: getCLOB not implemented for class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CVarcharAccessor
11:48:58,984 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.invocation] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component PackageHandling for method public PackageManagement.PackageHandling$FilteredPackageList PackageManagement.PackageHandling.getFilterPackages(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer,int,int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String): javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Invalid column type: getCLOB not implemented for class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CVarcharAccessor
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:166) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:230) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:173) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at PackageManagement.PackageHandling$$$view15.getFilterPackages(Unknown Source) [classes:]
    at org.apache.jsp.View.PackageManagement.Packages_jsp._jspService(Packages_jsp.java:289)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:489) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Invalid column type: getCLOB not implemented for class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CVarcharAccessor
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1361) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1289) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:261) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at PackageManagement.PackageHandling.getFilterPackages(PackageHandling.java:635) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Invalid column type: getCLOB not implemented for class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CVarcharAccessor
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:52) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.java:108) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at $Proxy27.getClob(Unknown Source) at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.ClobTypeDescriptor$4.doExtract(ClobTypeDescriptor.java:108) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:65) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:269) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:265) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:357) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2695) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1552) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1484) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1384) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:640) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:856) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2058) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3697) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:439) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:420) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:204) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:251) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:148) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:954) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:903) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:610) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:438) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:150) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1006) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:883) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2463) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2449) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2279) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2274) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1115) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:252) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: getCLOB not implemented for class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CVarcharAccessor
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.Accessor.unimpl(Accessor.java:412) [ojdbc5.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.Accessor.getCLOB(Accessor.java:1296) [ojdbc5.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getCLOB(OracleResultSetImpl.java:1540) [ojdbc5.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getClob(OracleResultSetImpl.java:686) [ojdbc5.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getClob(OracleResultSet.java:358) [ojdbc5.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedResultSet.getClob(WrappedResultSet.java:783)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_02]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.java:104) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    ... 105 more
```

I am using ojdbc6.jar Oracle 11.2. driver. I already tried with ojdbc5.jar, but without success. Any idea how to fix this?

In persistence.xml I am using the Oracle10gDialect.

Comment: Not enough information to go on, but could it be related to this: http://www.jpadbf.org/2010/02/jdbc-xmltype-and-ora-01461/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like the column in question is not a CLOB, but a VARCHAR and the Oracle driver does not seem to support getCLOB on a VARCHAR column. I base this on the part of the stacktrace, where the driver itself explicitly calls a method `unimpl` (I assume to throw the Exception) and that it mentions T4CVarcharAccessor:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: getCLOB not implemented for class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CVarcharAccessor
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.Accessor.unimpl(Accessor.java:412) [ojdbc5.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.Accessor.getCLOB(Accessor.java:1296) [ojdbc5.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
```

So it looks like the definition of the column and the expectations of Hibernate about its use do not match.

Comment: You were right. Although I defined the field as `@Lob`, it was created as `varchar2(255)`. It was working fine on previous JPA versions, but they fixed one bug, where they read CLOBs as normal Strings. Due to the fact that I also upgraded the JPA jars, it did not work anymore. Thanks for the answer.